# How to get value of app's location permission on Phonegap Android

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

I need to find out if location permission for current app is disabled or not.

I can use `cordova.plugins.diagnostic.isLocationEnabled` to check if global phone's location services are turned off or on, but that doesn't take into account permissions settings for current app.

I tried using `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` but it never fails if i disable location permission, it just times out giving me error code `3` which is timeout error. But I need to differentiate between request timeout and location permission being turned off

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found out the answer. This is Android 6 specific issue. It has 2 levels of location settings. Global and app's specific. `cordova.plugins.diagnostic` will add support for app's specific permission settings soon.

https://github.com/dpa99c/cordova-diagnostic-plugin/issues/11

Comment: I get the following error, any ideas please?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740031/error-ts2339-property-diagnostic-does-not-exist-on-type-cordovaplugins